# Is there a way to interface CiviCRM with QuickBooks Online?

Tags: accounting

We can probably use the existing QB interface to manually export accounting batches from CiviCRM and then import these in QBO, but I am specifically looking for a solution that would use QBO's RESTful APIs (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting) to automate this process as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agileware has developed a [CiviQuickbooks](https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks) extension - in this case "Quickbooks" means "Quickbooks online".

Answer (score 1):

JMA Consulting is interested in providing an extension which would implement this service. I will contact you directly about this so we can work up a spec and scope the work on http://wiki.civicrm.org.